# unable to launch LibGDX Particle Editor.jnlp

Tags: java, libgdx, particles

I am not able to launch LibGDX ParticleEditor.jnlp file on my system(win7 64 bit) with java7.

when I execute this file with javaws.exe in jre7/bin folder, it displays splash screen of **badlogic games** for jst 2-3 sec but after that it gives an alert having error message "**Unable to launch application**". And the exception is :

```
com.sun.deploy.net.JARSigningException: Found unsigned entry in resource: http://libgdx.googlecode.com/svn/jws/gdx-tools.jar
    at com.sun.javaws.security.SigningInfo.getCommonCodeSignersForJar(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.SigningInfo.check(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResourcesHelper(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareAllResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I've googled this problem,, but still unresolved. Please help me .

Comment: still waiting for an answer

Comment: You're probably better posting on the [LibGDX forums](http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/)

Comment: I've already posted that on forum.
http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=12498

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing you have 64 bit java installed. The ParticleEditor.jnlp fails to run on a 64 bit JRE.
What you would want to do is:

1. Download a 32 bit version of JRE. Here is the Oracle link for that: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-se-jre-7-download-432155.html
   Just make sure you select a "x86" version of the JRE from the list, appropriate for the platform you want to launch the .jnlp file on. (Mac is not supported as far as I know. In case it already is, please correct me.)
2. Assuming you're on Windows, locate the "javaws.exe" file under "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin" (of course, this is its location on my desktop, the location on yours should be similar). Notice the "C\:Program Files (x86)" folder - this is where all your x86 (32 bit) stuff goes - as opposed to "C:\Program Files", for 64 bit stuff.
3. Drag and drop your .jnlp file onto the javaws.exe file.

This should solve your issue.

The details of this answer are only here to help anybody who stumbles upon this issue - I was one of them until some time ago :-)

Comment: that was bull's eye

Comment: Glad it helped ;-)